# EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue on iphone and simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, iphone-4

I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS out side of my own code. Currently my code gets a URL through a shareURLCache object and then starts url connection. Once I leave the method that starts the url connection I hit the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I have tried using instruments to find any zombies and I have analysed for memory leaks and not turned up either. At this point I am completely stuck.

Here is the code that loads the url and starts the url connection

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"At new location: %@",newLocation);

    MKCoordinateRegion region = 
            MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([newLocation coordinate], 750, 750);

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [location stopUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [newLocation coordinate];
    NSURL *url = [urlCache getReccomendationForUID:@"12345" atLat:coord.latitude 
                                         atLon:coord.longitude forCategories:nil];


    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];


// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    if (connection) {
        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
        // xmlData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Could not create connection");
    }
}
```

Method from the sharedURLCache that returns the url

```
-(NSURL *)getReccomendationForUID:(NSString *)u atLat:(double)lat atLon:(double)lon forCategories:(NSArray *)cat
{
    if(remote) {
        NSMutableString *categories = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        for(NSString *s in cat) {
            [categories appendString:@"&cat="];
            [categories appendString:s];
        }
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recommendation?uid=%@&psw=null&lat=%f&lon=%f?%@",
                   apiRoot,u,lat,lon,categories];
        [categories release];
        return [NSURL URLWithString:s];
    } else {
        return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"XMLTest" withExtension:@"xml"];;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try retaining the URL returned by your method.

Comment: Posting the callstack at EXC_BAD_ACCESS time would help too. Plus anything else in the console.

Comment: There is no output to the terminal on the crash, the call stack contains objc_msgSend and <????>

Comment: I seem to have sovled the issue, I think it is a problem with the url being given NSURl. After swapping to using a twitter search @"http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?geocode=57.147683,-2.101564,0.5km" I am no longer hitting this issue. I had tested for this hoping url would be nil, but no such luck.

Comment: I was passing NSLog("Error blah blah) instead of NSLog(@"Error blah blah") in connection did fail with error. Problem finally solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just start by commenting out code and running to see if you can get the mem error to disappear then start adding code again until it appears, then you have a better idea where the issue is. it could be anywhere in your code since you seem to have a number of objects in there that are not passed in e.g. 'location'.

```
[location stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: I have tried doing this so far, execution falls out of my code at the end of the method and into objective-c libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had same memory issue with

```
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

This method doesn't like fast updates...